# How to implement openssl command in Titanium Alloy project?

Tags: javascript, openssl, certificate, titanium, sha1

How can I implement the command below or just implement openssl command in titanium?

```
openssl x509  -noout -fingerprint -sha1 -in <(openssl x509 -in <(openssl s_client -connect linkedin.com:443 -prexit 2>/dev/null))
```

It should give me a  SHA1 string.

Comment: why would you even need it / what is the purpose of it?

Comment: I'm trying to implement certificate pinning. This command will get the sha1 of the certificate of server certificate.